# Dynamics CRM Workflow for Marketing List Member Add/Remove

Tags: workflow, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

Is there a way to attach a workflow for Addition and Deletions from Marketing Lists.

I have not found a way either from the UI, nor the SDK.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accounts/contacts/leads are associated with marketing lists with a native N:N relationship. It is not possible to trigger workflows on association/disassociation in a N:N relationship.

Instead, you could create a plugin that triggers on the [Associate and Disassociate messages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328576.aspx).